"HTML Form Select Tag Issue: Only First Word of Multi-Word Selections Inserted into MySQL Table"
A single HTML select tag is populated by a MySQL database table. When a user selects an option containing multiple words and submits it, only the first word of the selection is saved.
This is the code for the HTML form:
<form action="submit_page.php" method="post">
    <label for="type_name">Transaction Type</label>
    
    <select name="type_name" id="type_name" required>
        <option class="select" disabled="" selected="">Select type...</option>
        

      <?php foreach ($rows as $row) {
         echo "<option value = ". $row['type_name'] . ">" . $row['type_name'] . "</option>";
                
      } ?>  
   </select> <br><br>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />


Always put quotes around attribute values in HTML. While it's optional when the value is a single word, it's safest to always do it. And you need it when the value is multiple words.
